# DomDocument getElementById not works?

Tags: php, domdocument

INPUT

```
<root id="root">
<p id="p1"><i>Title</i></p>
<p id="p2"><b id="b1">AAA<sup>1</sup>, BBB<sup>2</sup></b></p>
</root>
```

PHP code,

```
$dom2 = new DomDocument();
$dom2->loadXML( $input );
$e = $dom2->getElementById('p1');
    var_dump($e);
```

When I run, var_dump shows NULL... But *p1* is there, at `<p id="p1">`.

Answer (score 3):

You're loading an XML file which probably doesn't have a DTD which defines `id` attributes.

You could perhaps use Xpath to find those elements.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom2);
$element = $xpath->query("//*[@id='p1']")->item(0);
```

Comment: Thank Alex! Good remember that xpath can be used...  Hum... But I need a whole DTD for each "XML fragment" for use the getElementById method?  There are a workaround expressing a simpler DTD?

Comment: @PeterKrauss I haven't experimented with it, but there could potentially be a workaround.